# Can I fix a buck converter which was plugged in the wrong way? XL6009 Module

Tags: components, buck-boost

I've plugged a buck/boost converter in the wrong way (+ to -) and it instantly stopped working. Does anyone know if there is a quick fix like exchanging a diode? Which components should I measure to determine the broken component?

Im talking about a Automatic Converter XL6009 Module and the normal buck converter module.
[image]

Comment: Lets see the schematic of this buck-boost converter, along with suitable datasheets etc. Fixing this could be simple or could be impossible, depends on things you haven't told us.

Comment: Felix Prackwieser - Hi, (a) As commented above, if you want someone to review that *specific* module, see how it works, how it could have been damaged by connecting a reverse-polarity input, and write a detailed answer, that will need you to supply the correct schematic. On this site, we ask that for reverse-engineering & repair questions (which this effectively is) the OP should supply the schematic. Please find that & add it to the question. (b) In the question you mention both "buck/boost converter" and "buck converter". Those are *different* modules. Please clarify which you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I found some information, including a representative schematic: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/buck-boost-regulator-using-xl6009-with-adjustable-33v-to-12v-output-voltage The modules can be purchased for less than $1 so it's hardly worth trying to troubleshoot and repair.

Comment: @PStechPaul - Nicely found; that seems to match the (stock) photo in the question better than some other XL6009 schematics I found earlier. Unfortunately, we have an equal split between whether the OP has a *buck/boost* converter (the photo & 1 mention in the Q) or just a *buck* converter (the title & 1 mention in the Q). So the buck/boost module schematic you kindly found may or may not match the OP's *actual* module. Hopefully the OP can clarify and perhaps the schematic you found *might* allow progress, if they confirm that it matches their module.

Answer (score 2):

One common reverse polarity protection method is to use parallel diode along with a fuse:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBTytR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the supply is applied in reverse polarity, the fuse will blow and possibly the diode will go short. The circuit will quite possibly be protected because the negative input voltage will be clamped to a diode drop.

If that's the case in your circuit then you'll need to replace both fuse and diode.

Or, another possibility is that there's no protection whatsoever. In this case you'll need to recycle your circuit and buy/build another one (the easiest solution).

Comment: I have updated my description please reconsider. Thanks!